# How to achieve equal spacing in same height columns bootstrap?

Tags: css, laravel, grid, bootstrap-5

I am building a website to display images in an specific grid. I am using Laravel and Bootstrap for this project.

The goal is to create a grid with spacing that maintains the images heights. **To create a space between the divs I added a border right to the images, but when I do that it also creates a border bottom at the first two divs, which makes the first two images have a smaller height than the last one.:**

Image: https://gyazo.com/9bd97d19073a123966a652e3603ebfd4

[![As you can see the first two rectangles have a border bottom instead of just the border-right]

For reference this is the kind of grid that I am trying to create:
https://gyazo.com/337d9e044a56e327e0c7e69069ae5c17
https://www.zarahome.com/pt/%C3%BAltima-semana/cole%C3%A7%C3%A3o-c1020095502.html

This is the code I have so far:

```
   <div class="row g-0 mx-0">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Ky415Wt/imageonline-co-placeholder-image-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="border-right: 10px solid white;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Ky415Wt/imageonline-co-placeholder-image-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid style="border-right: 10px solid white;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r5LDwny/imageonline-co-placeholder-image-3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid" style="border-right: 10px solid white;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I simply dont understand why adding a border-right also adds a border-bottom. I tried adding a margin instead but this causes the bigger image to jump out of the row, like so:https://gyazo.com/5a785de16398756021dd843ba038cbc6

Could someone help me to achieve this result?
https://gyazo.com/337d9e044a56e327e0c7e69069ae5c17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coleague helped me achieve the best solution, so I will post what sworked in case someone faces the same issue:

```
<div class="d-row d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 100px">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Ky415Wt/imageonline-co-placeholder-image-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Ky415Wt/imageonline-co-placeholder-image-2.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/r5LDwny/imageonline-co-placeholder-image-3.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using Bootstrap 4 to create this since in your tags it shows `bootstrap-4`. The reason why your code would not work is that `g-0` comes from Bootstrap 5. It might have been that you looked at the Bootstrap v5 documentation.

If you are using bootstrap 4 then you can add `no-gutters` to the div containing `row`.

To keep the images the same height I'd add some custom css and add the `40vh` in there.

I have made an example for you to take a look at:
https://www.codeply.com/p/BqPXPxcP2j

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I am actually using bootstrap 5, I'm sorry I put the wrong tag at the question.

I tried using your suggestion, but fixing the height distorts the images in large screens https://gyazo.com/359e939e5118dc867dc0477d5559d935

Comment: No worries. The images becoming distorted might be due to that when setting a fixed height e.g. `40vh` you have to add `object-fit: cover;`. That way the image will fill up the space but will not be stretched out.